# confirm email address using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

The backend has created user and needs the email to be confirmed and it has sent out an to the address (see below)

Please confirm your account by clicking

after clicking on the link the user goes to the frontend I have the following route setup using ui.router:

.state('confirmemail', {
     url'/confirmemail',
     templateUrl: 'client/view/confirmEmail.html' })

how do I get this to route to this state using the above link and how do I access the user and code? 
thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use stateParams:

In the email:

```
<a href="yoururl/confirmemail/idoftheuser">Link</a>
```

In your config:

```
.state('confirmemail', { url'/confirmemail/:id', ... })
```

In your controller:

```
var myId = $stateParams.id;
// Then lookup user with myId
```

Comment: one quick question if I am passing two params like userid and code what would the code on the state look like?

Comment: Use querystring style params (confirmemail?id&code instead of a basic parameter (/confirmemail/:id).  See https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/url-routing#query-parameters

Answer (score 0):

The link the user clicks on should go to yoursite/confirmemail. Simple as that, just have them navigate to the route that matches the url in your state.

As for passing the information, I can think of a couple options. You could pass a querystring, yoursite/confirmemail?userId=123 or whatever, or you could set up your route to pass some sort of id (or whatever the information may be). Either would have basically the same result. Again, you would define this in your email link then capture it when that path is hit.

Example of passing id using angular:

```
.state('confirmemail', {
    url: '/confirmemail/:id',
    resolve: {
        id: function ($stateParams) {
            return $stateParams.id;
        }
    }
}
```

and set the link to yoursite/confirmemail/123 where 123 is the user id.

From there you can inject the id into a controller.